# Apache2 post installation

Tags: apache2, php, webserver

I use the following command to install Apache server:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

The installation process seems to have completed without any problems. When I point my browser to localhost:80, the following message comes (which tells the server is properly running)

```
It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

Now my problem is, where the server is installed in my machine? Where is the "docroot"? (I need the docroot to deploy new webpages)

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache stores its VirtualHost files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. Just after installation, only the default sites are there.

To find out the document root of the default site:

```
grep DocumentRoot /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

This usually yields the the following docroot (which you are looking for):

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```